# Laravel send mail to multiple recipent and add multiple files

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with my controller to send to multiple recipients a mail,

I get an illegal offset exception for my collection of mail adresse.

I tried to send the mail with only one user to see with my code to send multiple files works, it's work but when i check the mail the files are not loaded with the good extension i get something like :

[image]

When i update the code to get the extension with :

> $m->attach($files[$i])->getClientOriginalName();

i get the following exception :

> Swift_IoException Unable to open file for reading [banner.png]

What i'm doing wrong here ?

Hope someone could help me to resolve my two problems. Many thanks in advance

Here my controller :

```
public function postSendMassive(Request $request){

        $files = $request->file('uploads');

        $emails = Structure::where('type_structure_id', 4)->pluck('adresse_email_structure');

        $data = array(

            'subject' => $request->subject,
            'bodyMessage' => $request->texte
        );

        Mail::send('email.MassiveMail', $data, function($m) use ($data , $emails , $files)
        {

            $m->to($emails)
                ->subject('subject');
                $size = sizeOf($files); //get the count of number of attachments

                    for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++) {
                        $m->attach($files[$i]);
                    }
        });

        return back()->with('status', "Email envoyé");

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify full path to a file, not just a file name, it is well described here - https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#attachments

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->view('emails.orders.shipped')
                ->attach('/path/to/file');
}
```

Depending on where you keep your files, it could look something like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    $path = realpath('storage/uploads/' . $files[$i]);
    $m->attach($path);
}
```